# Does Elsevier Engineering Village include IEEE Journals or arXiv papers?

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar, ieee, elsevier, springer

I need to conduct a litertature review around the topics of learning-based control autonomous vehicles and I am currently identifying which databases to search. I have chosen IEEE Xplore, Elsevier Engineering Village and arXiv.org. Do any of these databases include all of the literature of any of the other databases? For example, I can find IEEE Journals through Engineering Village.

Furthermore, is there any overlap with SpringerLink articles with any of those previously mentioned? Should I use Google Scholar instead? It seems to not have such a detailed advanced search.

Answer (score 1):

IEEEXplore seems completely subsumed under Engineering Village. I've yet to find a paper on IEEEXplore that wasn't on EV.

I have had some arXiv papers pop up in EV, but a quick look shows me that not all arXiv papers can be found with EV.

Google Scholar works fine if you know the tricks to create effective search strings, like using a `*` to capture all word variances. Ex., `rehab*` could be rehabilitative, rehabilitated, rehabilitator, rehabilitation. Or `""` to clump a phrase, like "augmented reality" to ensure it doesn't just pull up papers with only the word "augmented"

Unfortunately, I don't do research in your area so I can't speak to whether these are the best databases for your purposes. An academic faculty member could help with this. If you are doing research independent of an academic institution, you can get a sense of this sometimes just by googling "autonomous vehicle journal," and seeing what you find. Also, searching for related conferences and seeing where they publish can be helpful.